# EWS Category search

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

i've a script on powershell to manage mailbox using EWS, however i'm not able to user the current filters and filter certain categories.

I would like filter categories that start by _ or * and apply to my current filters

```
$sfRead = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead, $True)

$WIPSubject = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, "Assigned")
$sfNot = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Not($WIPSubject)

$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And)
$sfCollection.add($sfRead)
$sfCollection.add($sfNot)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a wildcard search on the Subject then I would suggest that you use AQS for queries instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579420(v=exchg.150).aspx . SearchFilters don't support wildcards you have the ContainsSubString filter which will find partial string matches https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633645(v=exchg.80).aspx which is the closest.

Comment: i tried to use AQS keyword on a ContainsSubString, however i couldn't make it work adding it to the SearchFilters used above

Comment: You can't do that you have to use the QueryString in place of the Search filter. If something doesn't work show the code that doesn't work